# Can Not Delete Session And Cookie

Tags: php, session, cookies

Can Not Delete Session And Cookie

I am new to PHP sessions.
I have used cookies plenty in the past.
I can't seem to get rid of this cookie - no matter what I do!

I seem to be able to clear the session - but the cookie remains.

**I have tried all of these: .. and MORE:**

```
<?php

// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}

?>
```

*above from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php*

---

```
<script>
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
  eraseCookie(cookies[i].split("=")[0]);
</script>
```

---

**What would be some of the reasons why the cookies does not delete?**

Comment: You could give [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php#26966) snippet a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the working of a session in php. What happens is when you start a session a unique string is generated which acts as the cookie value for the session . All the data that you are storing inside the session are stored in a file corresponding to the unique string. Now when you destroy a session it does not destroy the session string but rather than that it destroys the values corresponding to that string that is stored on the server.

So even though the cookies are there but there is no data corresponding to it and hence for the next request the session would effectively be empty.

Comment: Thank you.
So you are saying" the data is gone but the cookie remains".
Is there a way to get rid of the cookie as well?
Just for clarity.

Comment: Can you answer "what would be some of the reasons why the **cookies do not delete**?"

Comment: as far as i remember the cookie is set to be destroyed at end of browsing session. Let me find the exact link for this

Comment: @georoot After using `setcookie` as the OP has, the cookie should be deleted upon the receipt of the response.

Comment: here couldn't find a link but here is an example screenshot http://picpaste.com/2015-09-17-044300_1366x768_scrot.png Notice here that the PHP session cookie is meant to expire at end of browsing session

Comment: @Spooky i think the browser expires session cookies only at the end of browsing session and not before that.

Comment: @geroot They should be deleted/expired before you close your browser if you use `setcookie`, that's the point.

Comment: @Spooky trying this setcookie (session_id(), "", time() - 3600); might destry the session cookie. although i have not tested this one.